# How to pass in credentials for lighthouse audit in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions, lighthouse

I'm trying to use [Lighhouse CI Action](https://github.com/treosh/lighthouse-ci-action) for my Github Actions workflows.

It works well with public pages.

I'm not used to using these tools, merely helping a team get it into their workflow.

My question is, is there a way to run these audits on deployed environments that sit behind authentication?

Or do I need to use the `staticDistDir` way?

This is primarily in the PR workflows. For when we merge to `main` and go public, we audit the new page.

```
      - name: Audit URLs using Lighthouse
        uses: treosh/lighthouse-ci-action@v7
        id: lighthouse_audit
        with:
          urls: |
            https://www.example.com/
          budgetPath: ./.github/workflows/budget.json
          uploadArtifacts: true
          temporaryPublicStorage: true
```

What I would love to do is have flags for basic auth as well.